# How to pass Authorization Bearer using retrofit?

Tags: android, authorization, retrofit2, bearer-token

Here I need to pass Authorization Bearer to get response from server in case of uploading file to server I am using retrofit.

I tried in two ways

1)

This is how I initialized in retrofit interface class

```
@POST("document/kycDocument/user/3")
Call<UploadKycpojo> uploadkycdoc(@Header("Authorization")String token, @Body UploadKycRequest uploadKycRequest);
```

This is how I called it from interface class

```
Call<UploadKycpojo> request = RestClient.getInstance(UploadIdActivtiy.this).get().uploadkycdoc("Bearer "+auth,uploadKycRequest);
```

2)

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
      @Override
      public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request newRequest  = chain.request().newBuilder()
            .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token)
            .build();
        return chain.proceed(newRequest);
      }
    }).build();

Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
    .client(client)
    .baseUrl(/** your url **/)
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
    .build();
```

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: what problem are you facing?

Comment: I m getting response from server but 403 error

Comment: this is response I m getting and it comes only when authorization bearer token is not passed or when it is wrong. below is my response
{"timestamp":1519390221702,"status":403,"error":"Forbidden","message":"Access Denied","path":"/paychec/document/kycDocument/user/3"}

Comment: can you give me your api and token ?

Comment: sure I will give

Comment: buddy can you send me personal chat link

Comment: is the response correct in POSTMAN?

Comment: @SantanuSur yes correct

Comment: check your body then.. are the model variables are same name as the json.. are you sure all of them are ok?

Comment: give a `/` before the URL in post

Comment: cause for sending header both approaches are fine..]

Comment: @SantanuSur yes I have checked the body as well

Comment: can you upload the POSTMAN screenshot?

Comment: ok do one thing..

Comment: call for a `ResponseBody` object instead of `UploadKycpojo` .. then parse the json by hand...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165724/discussion-between-sunil-p-and-santanu-sur).

Answer (score 4):

> Your retrofit interface method should be like this:-

```
@Multipart
@POST("document/kycDocument/user/3")
Call<UploadKycpojo> uploadkycdoc(@Header("Authorization")String token, @Part 
                                                   MultipartBody.Part file);
```

> And your calling statement would be like this:-

```
File file = new File(yourStringPath);

RequestBody requestFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), getRealPathFromURI(data.getData()));

MultipartBody.Part multipartBody =MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file",file.getName(),requestFile);

Call<UploadKycpojo> request = RestClient.getInstance(UploadIdActivtiy.this).get()
                                            .uploadkycdoc("Bearer "+auth,multipartBody );
```

Comment: Sure let me check bro

Comment: I have replied in personal chat please check

Comment: ya it should work don't know the second way worked for me

Answer (score 4):

You just need to add space before `Bearer` it's work for me try it:

```
  OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(new Interceptor()           {
  @Override
  public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
    Request newRequest  = chain.request().newBuilder()
        .addHeader("Authorization", " Bearer " + token)
        .build();
    return chain.proceed(newRequest);
  }
}).build();

 Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
.client(client)
.baseUrl(/** your url **/)
.addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
.build();
```

Answer (score 3):

I did try and it's working for me please refer below code:

```
@Multipart
@POST("document/kycDocument/user/3")
Call<UploadKycpojo> uploadkycdoc(@Header("Authorization")String token, @Part 
MultipartBody.Part file, @PartMap() Map<String,
        RequestBody> partMap);
```

And for API call use below method:

```
private void uploadkycdoc() {
MultipartBody.Part filePart;
    HashMap<String, RequestBody> requestBodyMap = new HashMap<>();
    requestBodyMap.put("imageSlide", RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), "front"));

    ApiInterface apiInterface = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
    Call<UploadKycpojo> uploadkycdocCall = null;

    File file = new File(getRealPathFromURI(fileUri, context));
    RequestBody requestFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("*/*"), file);
    filePart= MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file", file.getName(),
            requestFile);

    uploadkycdocCall = apiInterface.uploadkycdoc("Bearer " + token, filePart, requestBodyMap);

    uploadkycdocCall.enqueue(new Callback<UploadKycpojo>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<UploadKycpojo> call, Response<UploadKycpojo> response) {
            cancelProgressDialog();
            try {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {

                } else {

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<UploadKycpojo> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Sure @Vishal I will check and let you know

Comment: the code and remaining details I have posted on personal chat

Comment: I got it, only the thing is Authorization bearer we should not give in interface class instead I have followed the second way to pass Authorization bearer which I mentioned in my question

Comment: great I never use second way.

Comment: second method worked in my case, but both are correct.

Comment: You can accept my answer if it's useful to you so it's also useful to other user.

Answer (score 0):

**Kotlin Ex:**
retrofit Get request with AUTH HEADER

```
 @GET("api-shipping/Apps")
fun getApp(@Header("Authorization") auth: String) : retrofit2.Call<JsonObject>
```

call enqueue don't forget to add **Bearer with a space** in tokken

```
 val tokken =  "Bearer TOKKEN_Key"
 call.enqueue(object : Callback<JsonObject> {
        override fun onResponse(call: Call<JsonObject>, response: Response<JsonObject>) {
            
        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<JsonObject>, t: Throwable) {
            
        }

    })
}
```